# Loading images from directory at intervals

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is probably simple, and I've looked into trying to do this with AJAX/Javascript but can't find a good way to do it.

I have this code:

```
<?php
$dir = "uploads/*";
foreach(glob($dir) as $file)
{
echo '<img src="'.$file.'">';
}
?>
```

And I want the images to be loaded with intervals of time in between each one. They are all jpegs and the same size.

I was wondering if there is a way to load them with setInterval and AJAX? Or keep it all in PHP?

Comment: Have PHP output an array of image URLs. On the client side, a `setInterval()` function could pick off one array item at a time, use `document.createElement()` to build an image, and append it  to whatever container currently houses the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My solution:**

Receive all files from `php` at once via `ajax`, then use the `setTimeout` function to load the images every `X` seconds. This demo is fully functional with 4 images.

**getImages.php**

```
<?php
echo json_encode(glob("upload/*"));
?>
```

**images.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
       url: "http://888.com.de/stack/ajax_interval.php",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data){
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                (function(i) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $("#holder").append("<p><img src='"+data[i]+"'</p>");
                        }, 3000*i); //3000 = 3seconds
                    })(i);
                }      
            },
       failure: function(errMsg) {
            console.error("error:",errMsg);
       }
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="holder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set up your PHP to funciton like a RESTful API endpoint.

And like your question suggests, I could then use jQuery's [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) along with [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to refresh the images after whatever period of time you wish.

Here's an exmaple of how you can accomplish this (there are many, many other ways):

PHP File (get-refresh-imgs.php):

```
<?php
$dir = "uploads/*";

echo json_encode(glob($dir));
?>
```

JavaScript File (ajax-refresh.js):

```
$(function(){

  var intervalInMiliseconds = 10000;

  //comment out if you don't want to load images immediately
  refreshImgs();

  setInterval(function(){
    refreshImgs();
  }, intervalInMiliseconds);

  function refreshImgs(){
    var container = $('body'); //use whatever container you wish. I'm using body.

    $.getJSON('get-refresh-imgs.php', function(data){
      container.empty();
      data.forEach(function(el, indx, ary){
        container.append('<img src="' + el + '"/>');
      });
    });
  }

});
```

Then, include this in your HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax-refresh.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of JS file that could be used for your purpose. It's really simple - ajax is put into a function and that function is called using setInterval() of 5 minutes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval(loadImages, 300000); //5 minutes

    function loadImages() {
        $("#images-container").load("/your_script.php");
    }

});
```

If you put it together with your current php code - it should load it's output into the div with `id=images_container` every 5 minutes